Median calculation over windows - rangeBetween over months in pyspark databricks
I am working in databricks pyspark and I am trying to get the median over the last two months excluding the current month. Also, there are multiple accounts so this must be parttioned but account too.
from pyspark.sql.functions import months
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("account").orderBy('date').rangeBetween(-months(2), months(0))
df = df.withColumn('median',round(median('cost').over(windowSpec),3) )

but I get error message

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions/builtin.py:19025: FutureWarning: Deprecated in 4.0.0, use partitioning.months instead.
warnings.warn("Deprecated in 4.0.0, use partitioning.months instead.", FutureWarning)

Second code
from pyspark.sql.functions.partitioning import months
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("account").orderBy('date').rangeBetween(-months(2), months(0))
df = df.withColumn('median',round(median('cost').over(windowSpec),3) )

but I get error message

Argument col should be a Column or str, got int.

input:



account
date
cost




account1
2024-10-01
5.00


account1
2024-10-02
6.00


account1
2024-10-03
7.00


account1
2024-11-01
8.00


account1
2024-11-02
9.00


account1
2024-11-03
10.00


account1
2024-12-01
4.88


account1
2024-12-02
8.46


account1
2024-12-03
9.43



expected output:



account
date
cost
median




account1
2024-10-01
5.00
null


account1
2024-10-02
6.00
null


account1
2024-10-03
7.00
null


account1
2024-11-01
8.00
null


account1
2024-11-02
9.00
null


account1
2024-11-03
10.00
null


account1
2024-12-01
4.88
7.5


account1
2024-12-02
8.46
7.5


account1
2024-12-03
9.43
7.5




A few ques:
Q. is the date in yyyy-MM-dd format?
Q. what is the current month? if it is Dec 2024, why in your result  is the value of prev months null?

thanks! it was just an example with no relation of actual. I will take into consideration next time I post.

To obtain the median of the month-2 like this :
+--------+----------+----+------+
| account|      date|cost|median|
+--------+----------+----+------+
|account1|2024-10-01| 5.0|  null|
|account1|2024-10-02| 6.0|  null|
|account1|2024-10-03| 7.0|  null|
|account1|2024-11-01| 8.0|  null|
|account1|2024-11-02| 9.0|  null|
|account1|2024-11-03|10.0|  null|
|account1|2024-12-01|4.88|   6.0|
|account1|2024-12-02|8.46|   6.0|
|account1|2024-12-03|9.43|   6.0|
+--------+----------+----+------+

you can use this code :
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, round, expr, percentile_approx, sum
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


# Calculate a month_offset
df = df.withColumn("year", expr("YEAR(date)")).withColumn("month", expr("MONTH(date)"))
df = df.withColumn("month_offset", expr("year * 12 + month"))

# Define the windows spec with a range between -2 and -2 to get the month - 2
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("account").orderBy("month_offset").rangeBetween(-2, -2)


# Apply the median over the windows spec
df = df.withColumn(
    "median", 
    round(percentile_approx("cost", 0.5).over(window_spec),3) 
)

df.select("account", "date", "cost", "median").show()

I hope this will help you :)
